# SQL: Where in вместе с Where Not In

Tags: sql, база-данных, mysql

Всем привет! Я использую MySQL 5.

В таблице у меня есть следующие строчки

```
column1 --- column2
1 --- 2
1 --- 3
2 --- 2
```

У меня есть 2 входных списка:

1. Список "положительных" column2 значений.
2. Список "отрицательных" column2 значений.

Требуется вывести все column1, у которых (во всей таблице) есть "связь" (находятся в одной строчке-записи в таблице) с каким-то положительным column2. И при этом нет НИ ОДНОЙ строчки в таблице, где есть column1 и какое-то отрицательное column2.

Например, положительный список - "2", отрицательный - "3".

При таком подходе в выборке должна быть только одна строчка

```
2 --- 2
```

Я пытался написать запрос и вот к чему пришел:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column2 IN (2) AND WHERE column2 NOT IN (3);
```

Но я получаю на выходе 2 строчки:

```
1 --- 2
2 --- 10
```

Comment: ниче не понятно

Comment: нече не понятно? where column2 = 2; и все?

Comment: Изменил формулировку вопроса. Добавил раздел "Требуется", чтобы был понятен смысл.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Второй `WHERE` лишний:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column2 IN (2) AND column2 NOT IN (3);
```

> При таком подходе в выборке должна
> быть только одна строчка  `2 --- 10`

При таком подходе будет одна строчка: `1 --- 2`

Возможный вариант:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column2 IN (2) AND column1 NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT column1 FROM table WHERE column2 IN (3));
```

Comment: Да, сори. Я поправил формулировку вопроса.

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thank you, sir!

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, задача поставлена некорректно. Если у Вас оба списка ограничивают `column2`, то Вам нужно из списка положительных значений удалить все отрицательные, после чего делаете запрос только по очищенному списку положительных значений.

Comment: inso правильно ответил

Comment: Представь ситуацию. У тебя в таблице 2 строчки. Одна с положительным column2, другая с отрицательным column2. И там, и там column1 совпадает. Тебе его брать доставать не надо из-за "И при этом нет НИ ОДНОЙ строчки в таблице, где есть column1 и какое-то отрицательное column2.". А если брать по "очищенному" списку - эта строчка достанется из базы.

Comment: То, что я предлагаю, аналогично первому запросу из ответа inso, только работать будет быстрее. Из формулировки не ясно, как понимать "где есть column1". Что, имеется в виду проверка на null?

Comment: Правильный запрос вот этот: SELECT * FROM table WHERE column2 IN (2) AND column1 NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT column1 FROM table WHERE column2 IN (3));

Comment: А, ну тогда да.